Workflow Automator Issues
I'm a junior React develeoper currently as a Intern in a startup company. We are working on a project which includes workflow automator. Now I'm facing some issues to execute the flow and automate the flow within the platform. can anyone help to resolve this blocker?
I tried to implement and execute the flow when a new record is created in the database and the flow is active when i a new record created but i need to make it automate in the platform and apply the actions and execute the flow.
